# If a class are going to be pointer based an inner object have to be pointer based or not?

Tags: c++

I have a class A and class B. I can have a private or public class_B object inside class A. (myclassB)
Ok, I create my class_A objects on the heap:

```
classA = new classA();
classA->myclassB.property =1;  // in case myclassB is public.
classA->myclassB.function_x(33); // in case myclassB is public.
```

First ... How can I call myclassB ? stacky-clas ? fixed_class ?
Second... Am I to have any problem to do this ? Is best ? It does not matter?
Thanks

Comment: _What are you talking about?_

Comment: I assume English may not be your first language. That's alright, but can you please expand more on what you're trying to do? Increase your code sample and ask more specific questions to help us out. Are you looking for terminology?

Comment: Maybe you're familiar with another programming language? If you say which one, we can help by pointing out the differences with C++.

Comment: Just a try to answer your questions.. If you create a object of classA on heap, also classB will be on the heap. and if you delete the objectA also the objectB in it will be deleted. You should name classes like the purpose of the class. For Example, if classA calculates some values with methods like "add(int a, int b)" call it Calculator.class. Maybe this is something you want to know?

Comment: Thanks Jan. Yes this is what I want to know. Any compiling or running advantages if I do one thing onr another (create classB also as pointer based). Thanks. A last question to GMan. yes, I also am looking for terminology, what is the name of a object created on the heap or on the stack? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

No. If I have a class that internally has a normal object (no pointer), than it doesn't matter whether the outer object is a pointer or not, the inner object always gets accessed normally.

```
A stack_a, *heap_a;
heap_a = new A();

/* Inner object always uses normal access */
stack_a.b.test()
heap_a->b.test()
```

The opposite is true too, if a class internally uses a pointer to an object then it doesn't matter whether the outer object is a pointer or not, the inner object always uses pointer access.